# How to use multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use this code in a view:

```
<button type="submit" name="SB1" value="submit1"><i class="fa fa-save"> Save</button>
<button type="submit" name="SB1" value="submit2"><i class="fa fa-update"> Update</button>
```

, and this code in a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(string SB1) {
    switch(SB1) {
        case "submit1":
            // my code..
        case "submit2":
            // my code..
    }
}
```

However, SB1 string is `null`. also, I want use button not use `input` tag because I use `string` and `fa icon` in button value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Comment: @Aldwoni: I want use button no input tag.

Comment: Are you sure the buttons are inside of the form tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(string SB1) {
    switch(SB1) {
        case "submit1":
            // my code..
        case "submit2":
            // my code..
    }
    return View();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action('AddUser')">
  <button type="submit" name="SB1" value="submit1"><i class="fa fa-save"> Save</button>
  <button type="submit" name="SB1" value="submit2"><i class="fa fa-update"> Update</button>
</form>
```

By this way, You will get appropriate name of button being click.

Comment: I use this and send null SB1 value.

Comment: @mishicaro, i don't know but its tottaly worked here, even i create sample project for this issue which is work as expected related to you're requirement.

Comment: i don't know why, but let me try to upload same thing on other source so that we both can verify this functionality

Answer (score 2):

make both a type button and on click, you can make ajax call :

```
<button type="button" name="SB1" onliclick=save()><i class="fa fa-save"> Save</button>
<button type="button" name="SB1" onliclick=update()><i class="fa fa-update"> Update</button>

<script>
    function save() {
        $.ajax({
            //call for first code
        });
    }
    function update() {
        $.ajax({
            //call for second code
        });
    }
</script>
```

or you can put on button click using jquery like in below URL:https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

one another way you can check below link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-multiple-submit-buttons-on-single-view-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: I want use one action in controller and not use ajax for submit

Comment: Go with this solution is it ok :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-multiple-submit-buttons-on-single-view-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")'"><i class="fa fa-save"></button>
```

YourAction: AddUser / UpdateUser

Comment: I want use one action not multi action, so use Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController", new {SB1 = "submit1"}) in onclick event button. but send null SB1 in action.

Comment: So you need to use Ajax: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/post-the-data-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Is there a solution other than Ajax?

Comment: You should separate into 2 actions to follow SRP principle:  https://deviq.com/single-responsibility-principle/

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't a `POST` return either a model or a `FormCollection`?

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(FormCollection form) 
{
    string SB1 = form.Get("SB1");
    switch(SB1) {
        case "submit1":
            // my code..
        case "submit2":
            // my code..
    }
    return View();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action('AddUser')">
  <button type="submit" name="SB1" value="submit1"><i class="fa fa-save"> Save</button>
  <button type="submit" name="SB1" value="submit2"><i class="fa fa-update"> Update</button>
</form>
```